# Mysqlimport very slow when importing two smaller files

Tags: mysql, bigdata, large-files, mysqlimport

I am trying to import a large file, it was really big and it did not seem to be working so I broke it into pieces. The first piece takes 2 minutes, and the second one takes almost an hour!!! How can that be???

```
bash-3.2$ wc -l allelePiecesaa 
2575063 allelePiecesaa
bash-3.2$ cp allelePiecesaa allele.txt
bash-3.2$ time /usr/bin/mysqlimport -h bluemoon-mgmt1a -u jbond --delete --local --fields_escaped_by=\\ MBSR -L allele.txt
MBSR.allele: Records: 2575064  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 6
real    1m50.285s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.103s
bash-3.2$ cp allelePiecesab allele.txt 
bash-3.2$ wc -l allele.txt 
2545972 allele.txt
bash-3.2$ time /usr/bin/mysqlimport -h bluemoon-mgmt1a -u jbond --local --fields_escaped_by=\\ MBSR -L allele.txt
MBSR.allele: Records: 2545973  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 7
real    57m17.279s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.097s
```

my configuration is:

```
[client]
user=X
host=Y
password=Z
port=3306

[mysqld]
init_connect='SET autocommit=0'
init_connect='SET foreign_key_checks = 0'
init_connect='SET unique_checks = 0'
log_slow_queries = 0
```

Any help appreciated.  Thanks,
Ramiro

Answer (score 0):

Second file doesn't have any issue.

It took more time on second file to import due to the fact that first file query or some query was pending to complete.

To check second file, you can restart mysql and try import again. It should take less time.